# Equalizer setEnabled returns invalid operation error

Tags: android, equalizer

I'm trying to create a simple equalizer for my music player application, following the [AudioFxDemo](http://gitorious.org/0xdroid/development/blobs/90c1d502521db52322dc5f96973d376e8029ac0a/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/AudioFxDemo.java) I've created a simple activity in witch I've 4 different seekbars that should change the volumes of some bands.
For now I have my MediaPlayer and Equalizer instantiated in the MainActivity that calls my EqualizerActivity, I've set the equalizer variable as a public static so that I can get it into my EqualizerActivity.

```
//MediaPlayer
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        equalizer = new Equalizer(0, mp.getAudioSessionId());
        int val = equalizer.setEnabled(true);
        if(val != Equalizer.SUCCESS)
            Log.v("A", "EQUALIZER NON ATTIVO");
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

My problem is that the equalizer.setEnabled(true) returns ERROE_INVALID_OPERATION (-5) instead of SUCCESS, at this point I've got the code working but I can't use the equalizer.
I really don't know what's the problem, but I think it could be that I'm setting the equalizer as static, is the another way to pass the equalizer to the EqualizerActivity?

```
public class EqualizerActivity extends Activity {

private Equalizer equalizer;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    equalizer = MainActivity.equalizer; //preso dall'activity -> sempre attivo
    int val = equalizer.setEnabled(true);
    if(val != Equalizer.SUCCESS)
        Log.v("A", "EQUALIZER NON ATTIVO " + val);
    setupEqualizerFXandUI();

}


//generato dinamicamente a seconda delle bande percepite
private void setupEqualizerFXandUI()
{
    TextView eqTextView = new TextView(this);
    eqTextView.setText("Equalizer:");
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    ll.addView(eqTextView);

    setContentView(ll);

     short bands = equalizer.getNumberOfBands();
     final short minEQLevel = equalizer.getBandLevelRange()[0];
     final short maxEQLevel = equalizer.getBandLevelRange()[1];

     for(short i = 0; i< bands; i++)
     {
         final short band = i;
         //Log.v("A", "B "+ band);
         TextView freqTv = new TextView(this);
         freqTv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
         freqTv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
         freqTv.setText((equalizer.getCenterFreq(band) /1000) + " Hz");
         ll.addView(freqTv);

         LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
         row.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

         TextView minDbTv = new TextView(this);
         minDbTv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
         minDbTv.setText((minEQLevel / 100) + " dB");

         TextView maxDbTv = new TextView(this);
         maxDbTv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
         maxDbTv.setText((maxEQLevel / 100) + " dB");

         LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         layoutParams.weight = 1;

         SeekBar bar = new SeekBar(this);
         bar.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
         bar.setMax(maxEQLevel - minEQLevel);
         bar.setProgress(equalizer.getBandLevel(band)); // Volume della banda

         bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                equalizer.setBandLevel(band, (short)(progress + minEQLevel));
                Log.v("A", "LEVEL: " + (progress + minEQLevel));
            }
        });

         row.addView(minDbTv);
         row.addView(bar);
         row.addView(maxDbTv);

         ll.addView(row);

     }

}
```

}

In the MainActivity I release the equalizer:

```
public void onDestroy()
{
        super.onDestroy();

        if(mNotify != null)
            mNotify.cancel(001);
        if(mHandler != null)
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask); //rimuovo il thread che aggiorna la seekbar
        if(mp != null){
            mp.release(); //rilascio il media player
        }
        if(equalizer != null)
            equalizer.release();
        if(bassboost != null)
            bassboost.release();
}
```

Comment: Are you doing any other equalizer operations in MainActivity?

Comment: Also, confirm if this behaviour is on the device or emulator ? If on device, what is the behaviour on emulator?

Comment: Testing on my device (galaxy S2), just tried on the emulator and I still got the error. The only other thing I'm doing with equalizer is declaring it as public static equalizer and releasing it when I close the application. I really can't figure it out

Comment: What exactly you are doing the release of equalizer ?  onDestroy?

Comment: sorry, meant Where exactly are you doing the release of equalizer ? onDestroy ?

Comment: yes, adding that to my top comment

Comment: I did a similar program from AudioFxDemo, made two tasks, and it works perfectly for me.  One thing you can try is to remove the setEnabled in MainActivity. I could help you debug this further if you could share MainActivity source (you can remove the non-relevant code, but ensure it is compilable)

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23802589/EqualizerTest.rar I've made this simple project showing what I've done with the equalizer, still doesn't work (to test it remember to change the string SONG_PATH to a path of a file audio). Thanks for all the effort you are putting to helping me out, I really don't know what to do, if you could also share your code I could try to figure it out where I messed up.

Comment: Your code worked correctly on my emulator, I did not face the issue at all, setEnabled on equalizer always returned SUCCESS !  Also checked on my Galaxy S3, worked fine. Can you create a new emulator an check once ? Also is your mp3 any special (ie., DRM encrypted, huge etc )?

Comment: I've tried it on the emulator and it works fine, I really can't understand why it doesn't work on my device (a galaxy S2).

Comment: Ok, seems like that n7player (a music application I'm using) had a process that took the equalizer with the highest priority (I think). Closing the n7player process I'm able to use the equalizer (I'm just having some problem with the sliders). Thanks for your help, I'm leaving the project up for other people to see, hope that in future this could help someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems like that n7player (a music application I'm using) had a process that took the equalizer with the highest priority (I think). Closing the n7player process I'm able to use the equalizer and the bass booster.

Answer (score 0):

> the priority – an equalizer engine can be shared by a number of apps. Each app provides a priority when they create their equalizer object. The app with the highest priority controls the engine.

But i am unable to find a way to set **my Equalizer with highest priority**.`Let me know if someone find a solution.`

**Edit**

I think i find a solution.but i haven't tested it yet.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mEqualizer.hasControl() == false) {
        prepareEqualizer();//force re-gaining control
    }
}
```